# Keep away vs. Keep aloof

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between these phrasal verbs or both mean the same.

For instance;

Keep away from my brother

Keep aloof from my brother

Answer (score 1):

"Aloof" in this sense is now a literary word. I don't think many people would use it in ordinary conversation, except as an adjective meaning " Lacking affection or warmth of feeling, often in a manner suggesting a (disproportionate) sense of one's own superiority;" (from the OED)

So I would expect to hear

> He seems very aloof.

much more often than

> He kept aloof from ...

Answer (score 0):

To **keep away** has the meaning that there is planning involved in staying away from your brother. For example, you consciously ignore your brother by not answering his phone calls.

To **be aloof** / **stay aloof** /**keep aloof** has more the meaning of being unpredictable in staying away from your brother. For example, you might be ignoring your brother because you are distracted by something else.

Comment: Does anyone really use "keep aloof"? I have never heard or read it. In any case, actual example sentences for these phrases should be added to your answer.

Comment: @user3169: Historically, "keep aloof" was the only correct form. Since 1900, the other two forms have gained popularity, and are now very similar in usage to "keep aloof". https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=be+aloof%2Cstay+aloof%2Ckeep+aloof&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbe%20aloof%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstay%20aloof%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ckeep%20aloof%3B%2Cc0